# Tricks to lose weight in 48 hours

Tags: weight-loss

In the past 3 months I've lost 12.5kg/28 pounds doing it the "right" way:
Regular exercise with regular small low-fat meals.

I'm 178cm/5.84 feet and now weigh 73.5kg/162 pounds.

The biggest motivator to have kept this up might sound very silly and "wrong" but it worked: I made a bet with a friend that I could lose 14kg in 14 weeks.

Those 14 weeks end in 4 days, on Wednesday, and I still have 1.5kg to go.
At the moment the weight loss obviously goes slower than when I still was carrying a bucket of fat on my body.

I really don't want to lose the bet on a couple of grams so **I'm looking for some kind of unhealthy brute-force attack I can do on my body to drop a lot of weight in the last days.**

Some extra info:

- **I especially need advice on how much water to drink** and at what time. I currently drink a lot of water but I guess I should stop that at some point?
- Remember that just as a boxer, I **know the exact time I will be standing on the scale.**
- **I'm fully aware that this is unhealthy** and that I will gain that weight back by Thursday.

Comment: You could try eating absolutely nothing at all and doing a heavy work out to drain your body of water. It might be unhealthy, but then again it's only temporarily.

Comment: So, let us know the weigh in and if you won.

Comment: Will do, yesterday I already reached -13.6 (so 400 grams/0.9 pound left) so I'm already pretty sure I'll make it. :-)
I ate very small doses this weekend and slept a lot.

Comment: Do did you make it?

Comment: Yes, I did make it, even 2 days earlier. exercising heavily with warm clothes helped enormously

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay...I have the answer.  I'm a bodybuilder, so this is the kind of stuff we do...

Do not lift heavy weights for large muscle groups.  I will make you swell.
Do not do a colon cleanse this close.  It can make you hold water.

However much water you drank on Sunday, do the same on Monday.
Assuming you drank a gallon or more of water Sunday, Drink half of that on Tuesday before 6pm.
After 6pm, only sip as needed totaling less than a pint between 6pm Tuesday and 12pm Wednesday.
I'm assuming you're weighing in at 12pm Wednesday, so adjust accordingly.

Stop eating all carbohydrates immediately, including fruit.  Also stop any dairy products.
Only eat protein and veggies with no sodium added.
For protein, do not eat egg whites.  I suggest ground turkey of ground beef.
For veggies, I suggest asparagus because it is also a natural diuretic.

As for exercise, just sweat as much as possible.
Do not soak in a tub or hot tub.  Dry sauna would be fine.
On Tuesday and Wednesday, only shower very quickly...in and out.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to accept this as answer because of the details and timeline.

Comment: This is an old answer, but another tip I've heard from wrestlers aiming to make weight is to chew gum and *spit*, its gross but can get you a solid and needed 500g.

Answer (score 7):

The most important thin you could do is get up and move around. A lot. Move your legs, don't let the blood and water pool in your ankles. Heavy exercises that make you sweat a lot such as squats and dead lifts. If you don't weight lift then get out and run or bike hard. If you have access to a sauna, us it.

As for your diet, cut back on carbs. They are hydrophilic which means they soak up water. And drink lots of water. Contrary to what you might expect, your body wont hold onto water if you're not dehydrated. Try drinking a half gallon or more of water each day.

Comment: Yes, in this time frame (and using scale weight as the measure) all you can do is get rid of water/glycogen, which means convincing your body to get rid of the excess water it has and staying away from carbs so that you don't accumulate more.

Comment: should I stop drinking a lot in the last day?

Comment: You can stop drinking and eating all together on the last day if you want. Or weight yourself before you do eat and drink.

Answer (score 5):

My wife and I wanted to lose weight very quickly in 2 days and found a pineapple diet.  Simplistically, all we ate pineapples 3 times a day, a large tin, and one banana as a treat.  I don't know how, I don't know why, but we both lost 10 lbs in 2 days.  I am guessing most of it was water, as we spent an inordinate amount of time on the toilet, but it worked.

Other than that, get over to Dhaka and eat off the food stalls in the streets.  I lost 47lbs in 2 weeks.  Bit drastic, and I couldn't move for two weeks, through energy loss and the need to be within sight of a toilet 24/7, but it worked...

Comment: Pineapple has bromeline which is a natural diuretic.  Also, it is very low calorie.

Comment: Go to a Brazilian restaurant.  Eat meat, lots of meat, until you are full.  Then have their cinnamon roasted pineapple for desert. You'll see why it's good for losing weight.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [colon cleansing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_cleansing). That's pretty drastic. But not really sure how long it takes.

Comment: wow.. eh.. the bet is only 100 bucks so no thanks :-)

Comment: LOL!!!  Oh, so no pride involved.  Ok.  ;-)

Comment: Hosing out your butt takes about an hour or 2 and will make you miserable, but it *will* get a couple pounds of poop out of you reasonable quickly.

Comment: Ya I agree with Salsero that you should at least try [Colon Cleansing](http://www.colonhealthmagazine.com/colonhealth) and decide for yourself whether it works for you or not.

Answer (score 3):

In wrestling we used water weight loss for quick weight loss. Yes it isn't permanent and it isn't particularly healthy. It was not unusual for me to lose 5 to 7 pounds (2-3 kg) in water weight per workout before the weigh-in.

Comment: And how did you do that?

Comment: sweats, heated room and lots of motion with no liquid intake.

Comment: I think my mouth would go dry real quick.  Don't know if I'd be able to handle this.