# How to lose weight in about 32 hours

Tags: weight-loss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tricks to lose weight in 48 hours](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/tricks-to-lose-weight-in-48-hours)

I have a photoshoot Saturday morning and I'm looking for ways to lose weight for me to be able to fit into my dress. Unfortunately, today was thanksgiving. I tried not to eat as much but I still am not able to fit into my dress. I'm looking to lose about 5-10 pounds... any help?

Comment: Seems like a [duplicate to this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/1488/3941) except that the timeframe is slightly different.